# What is this type of lure or where can I find more?

Tags: fishing, fishing-tackle

[image]

Can anyone help me find more of these lures? I love them so much but can’t find them anywhere. Does anyone know where to get these or what they are called. It has a paddle tail and a ribbon tail type thing on the bottom.